# [Forge 1.8.9]: SnakeYAML crashes Minecraft

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-forge, snakeyaml

I'm developing a mod with the Forge MDK for Minecraft 1.8.9. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to edit and run the code. Everything works when I'm running the code directly in IntelliJ, but it crashes when I build the jar and run it in Minecraft. Here's the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 18/05/22 5:06 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:162)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:739)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:495)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:329)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:210)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:245)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
    at enderix.falldamageindicator.Functions.loadProperty(Functions.java:17)
    at enderix.falldamageindicator.FallDamageIndicator.reload(FallDamageIndicator.java:63)
    at enderix.falldamageindicator.FallDamageIndicator.init(FallDamageIndicator.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:211)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:189)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:737)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:954)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:899)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:882)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 51 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.9
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_302, International Business Machines Corporation
    Java VM Version: Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210730_192 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 1851b0074
OMR      - 9db1c870d
JCL      - de702c3174 based on jdk8u302-b08), Eclipse OpenJ9
    Memory: 238112992 bytes (227 MB) / 462684160 bytes (441 MB) up to 4194304000 bytes (4000 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -Xoptionsfile=C:\Program Files\Semeru\jdk-8.0.302.8-openj9\jre\bin\default\options.default -Xlockword:mode=default,noLockword=java/lang/String,noLockword=java/util/MapEntry,noLockword=java/util/HashMap$Entry,noLockword=org/apache/harmony/luni/util/ModifiedMap$Entry,noLockword=java/util/Hashtable$Entry,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodType,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/CollectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConstructorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ConvertHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ArgumentConversionHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/AsTypeHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ExplicitCastHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FilterReturnHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ReceiverBoundHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/DynamicInvokerHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/FieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldGetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/StaticFieldSetterHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/IndirectHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InterfaceHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VirtualHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/PrimitiveHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeExactHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/InvokeGenericHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/VarargsCollectorHandle,noLockword=java/lang/invoke/ThunkTuple -Xjcl:jclse29 -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xms400m -Xmx4000m
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.19 Powered by Forge 11.15.1.2318 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
    UCHI    mcp{9.19} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
    UCHI    FML{8.0.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9-universal.jar) 
    UCHI    Forge{11.15.1.2318} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.8.9-11.15.1.2318-1.8.9-universal.jar) 
    UCHE    fdi{1.1} [Fall Damage Indicator] (falldamageindicator-1.1.jar) 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '4.6.0 - Build 30.0.101.1340' Renderer: 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'
```

**NOTE:** I only have 1 dependency: SnakeYAML

Comment: The SnakeYAML jar or class files will have to get loaded by Minecraft somehow for this to run. I don't know Forge, but if you can't find a way to give Minecraft the SnakeYAML jar to load, you could always include its contents in your jar.

Comment: Where did you put the SnakeYAML jar exactly?

Comment: I didn't use the SnakeYAML jar. I just added it as a dependency in the `build.gradle` file. Was I supposed the add the jar somewhere?

Comment: Why don't use the YAML module included in spigot ? And yes, if you want to use your own you need to put it in your jar

Comment: I'm not using Spigot, I'm using Forge. Sorry if I was not clear on that.